# Benefits of running sha512 hash function several times

Tags: javascript, hash, sha512

I have seen this piece of code in a publication. What benefits does it bring to generate the hash 11 times? Is it more secure than one because of entropy?

```
var hash = sha512(salt+":"+user+":"+passwd);
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    hash = sha512(salt+":"+user+":"+passwd);
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I'd say benefit could be that if some hash is in some rainbow  table eg. `"somepassword" > "some-hash"`, then if you'd hash it multiple times it would not be found on such table or it would require this table to be 10 times bigger.

Comment: This exact piece of code? It's exactly the same as running she SHA512 once - there is no actual change to the entropy. At most, it's to make it take slightly longer (to prevent brute forcing) but I really doubt it's going to be effective.

Comment: Running the same hash repeatedly becomes more secure because recreating the hashes in a brute force manner becomes more computationally expensive. Check out some of the answers to [this question](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/115406/is-it-more-secure-to-hash-a-password-multiple-times)

Comment: Actually, re-reading this - the actual posted code offers absolutely no benefits. The _exact same_ hash will be generated 11 times. It's literally the same as generating the hash once. First time I read it I thought it was running the SHA512 on the previous hash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The final hash value in this example is not any more secure (nor even any different whatsoever) than if it were hashed once. The only effect I can see from the provided code is that it takes longer.

Regarding some of the links, comments and other answer regarding repeated hashing, this is only meaningful if the subsequent hash functions are applied to the **output** of the previous hash. The asker's example simply hashes the same data over and over, producing the same result.

This code might be more effective:

```
var hash = sha512(salt+":"+user+":"+passwd);
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    hash = sha512(salt+":"+user+":"+passwd+":"+hash);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is more secure in cases that an attacker gains access to the database containing the hashed passwords.

Having it hashed multiple times will slow down the attacker by a factor linear to the number of hash iterations while trying to guess the plain passwords from the hashes using brute force attack.

In that perspective, I would say that 10 is a rather small number and if this case (an attacker gains access to passwords database) is a concern to you, I guess it is better to to more iterations than 10 (say 1000).

Edit: I just noticed that in the question the repeating hash is always using the original password, and it is not hashing it over and over again like the following code

```
var hash = sha512(salt+":"+user+":"+passwd);
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    hash = sha512(salt+":"+user+":"+hash);
```

My response refers to this case (hashing the hash over and over again) and not to the code mentioned in the question.

Comment: And it should be noted, that this is a very poor implementation of key-stretching, there is a proven way to do this iterations called [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2).